# Swift: Trying to encode user and pass into UTF8

Tags: swift, encoding

I am using an API that does not take headers to validate user credentials in a log in screen. I want to encode the email and pass into UTF8 in case there are characters such as a "+" in an email or pass. Here is my code:

```
func logIn() {


    var email = emailTextField.text
    var pass = passwordTextField.text

    var encodedEmail = email.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLHostAllowedCharacterSet())
    var encodedPass = pass.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLHostAllowedCharacterSet())

    var url = "https://www.photoshelter.com/psapi/v3/mem/authenticate?api_key=\(api_key)&email=\(encodedEmail!)&password=\(encodedPass!)&mode=token"


    var baseURL:NSURL? = NSURL(string: url)
    var request: NSMutableURLRequest? = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: baseURL!)
    var session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    var task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in


            if response == nil {
                UIAlertView(title: "PhotoShelter", message: "No internet connection", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "Cancel").show()
            } else {
                var responseObject: AnyObject? = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: nil, error: nil)
                var status: AnyObject? = responseObject?.objectForKey("status")

                if status as String != "ok" {
                    UIAlertView(title: "PhotoShelter", message: "Invalid Credentials", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK").show()
                } else {

                    var tokenString: AnyObject? = responseObject?.objectForKey("data")
                    var token: AnyObject? = tokenString?.objectForKey("token")
                    println(token!)


                }

            }

        })
    })
    task.resume()
}
```

It runs fine, and I get the token printed no issues with a regular log in. When I add an email with a "+" the baseURL does not read it. It converts the "@" sign into %40 but ignores the "+".

I would also like to note that when I used:

```
var encodedEmail = email.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
var encodedPass = pass.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

It did not work either. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is doing what you're asking. You just aren't asking the correct thing. You are asking it to take a string and convert all characters **not** in the given NSCharacterSet with percent encodings. (BTW, you are not trying to encode a username and password into UTF-8, you are trying to percent-encode them, or URL encode.)

The character set you are passing includes +, because, + is allowed in URLs.

To get the result you want, you need to give a character set that does not include +. I don't know of any good, URL-oriented predefined sets that do that, so you must make your own. This is one way to go about it:

```
import Foundation

let x: NSString = "some+other@host.xxx"
let modifiedHostCharacterSet: NSMutableCharacterSet = NSCharacterSet.URLHostAllowedCharacterSet().mutableCopy() as NSMutableCharacterSet
modifiedHostCharacterSet.removeCharactersInString("+")

x.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(modifiedHostCharacterSet)
```

That snippet is meant to be demonstrating your desired outcome in an Xcode playground or REPL.